# scrolling table: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, memory-management

i've been dancing with a tambourine for a while, but still don't know what's the reason for that error.
I've got a tableView with history of user queries data from sqlite base. I'm new to iPhone developing, so my code may be a bit excessive. The hierarchy is:

- **HistoryModel**
  model-object with some init methods
- **HistoryDataController**
  gets data from database and presents an array of HistoryModel objects
- **HistoryViewController**
  subclass of UITableView, displays data
- **AppDelegate**
  there i initially store an array of HistoryModel objects (by getting it from HistoryDataController) for HistoryViewController to access it.

**The problem is, when i scroll the table or open the tab with it for the second time - it crashes** with *-[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance*

Code:

**HistoryModel.h**
pretty unnecessary class for that case, but i want that worked to repeat in several identical cases, but a bit more complicated

```
@interface HistoryModel : NSObject {
    int entry_id;
    NSString *word;
}

- (id)initWithWord:(NSString *)word;
- (id)initWithWord:(NSString *)word andId:(int)entry_id;

@property int entry_id;
@property (retain) NSString *word;

@end
```

HistoryModel.m

```
@implementation HistoryModel

@synthesize entry_id, word;

- (id)initWithWord:(NSString *)_word {
    [super init];
    word = _word;
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithWord:(NSString *)_word andId:(int)_entry_id {
    entry_id = _entry_id;
    return [self initWithWord:_word];

@end
```

**HistoryDataController.h**
i use the entity of that class as getter of data and a storage for HistoryModel objects (in historyEntries property)

```
@interface HistoryDataController : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *historyEntries;
    int limit;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *historyEntries;
@property int limit;

- (id)initWithHistoryData;
- (id)initWithHistoryDataLimitedBy:(int)limit;
```

HistoryDataController.m

```
@implementation HistoryDataController
@synthesize historyEntries, limit;

- (id)initWithHistoryDataLimitedBy:(int)_limit {
    [super init];

    // Getting data from database
    {some DB stuff}

    NSMutableArray *tmp_historyEntries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    while(result == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        HistoryModel *currentHistoryEntry = [[HistoryModel alloc] initWithWord:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)] ];
        [tmp_historyEntries addObject:currentHistoryEntry];
        result = sqlite3_step(statement);
    }
    historyEntries = tmp_historyEntries;

    {some DB stuff}
    return self;
}
@end
```

**HistoryViewController.h**
subclass of UITableViewController, gets data stored in AppDelegate's property and displays in the table

```
@interface HistoryViewController : UITableViewController {
    IBOutlet UITableView *historyTable;
    SynonymsAppDelegate *appDelegate;
}

@property (retain) UITableView *historyTable;

@end
```

HistoryViewController.m

```
@implementation HistoryViewController
@synthesize historyTable, historyEntriesToShow;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    appDelegate = (SynonymsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate initHistoryList];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    {standart cell stuff}

    HistoryModel *historyEntry = [appDelegate.historyList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = historyEntry.word;
    return cell;
}

@end
```

**SynonymsAppDelegate.h**
when history tab opens, it gets data of historyList property, that was formed by HistoryDataController :)

```
@interface SynonymsAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
    ...
    NSMutableArray *historyList;
}
...
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *historyList;

- (void)initHistoryList;

@end
```

SynonymsAppDelegate.m

```
@implementation SynonymsAppDelegate
@synthesize window, tabBarController, historyList;

- (void)initHistoryList {
    HistoryDataController *historyDataController = [[HistoryDataController alloc] initWithHistoryData];
    historyList = historyDataController.historyEntries;
}

@end
```

Fuf. Sorry for so much code, but i believe that's all necessary. 
As a result of half the day spent on this question, i may guess, that problem is somehow connected with HistoryModel entity, because when i delete "retain" for *word* @property, the error switches for *-[CFString isEqualToString:]: message sent to deallocated instance*

I'm not really experienced in memory management, but i guess this *HistoryModel* objects inside *historyEntry* in *HistoryViewController* or in *historyList* in *AppDelegate* **releases** somehow, when scrolling the table or opening the tab for the second time.
But this's just my guessing.
Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Pretty long, yet important parts are missing. For NSString properties, you almost always want (copy) instead of retain. More code for your HistoryModel might be useful. Probably the code is elsewhere, though - maybe a release to an autoreleased NSString.

Comment: Don't know if this is the problem, but I think you need a retain in your appDelegate: historyList = [historyDataController.historyEntries retain];

Comment: Thanks, i tried all you've proposed, still that has't solved the problem. For Eiko: that's all code of HistoryModel i've got, except for init methods, which, as i mentioned, aren't used anyway. Rengers, i tried your solution, it didn't help but i'll try to retain other objects. In fact, i haven't done memory management at all yet, cuz i'm not experienced in it and this is just the very beginning of the program.

Comment: ... So it's very unlikely that i've released any of objects manually.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going wrong from this cod3, but what I would do is make sure you use the synthesized getter and setter everywhere possible. For example in HistoryDataController.m, do self.historyEntries = tmp_historyEntries. Or better yet, skip the whole tmp_historyEntries. But as you've stated, you didn't release anything manually so it's unlikely this would fix it. Still, it's good practice :)

Comment: thanks, but the result is the same ) when i make initializing of HistoryDataController each time the tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath: function iterates rows (inside it) it works pretty stable, but this is ineffective, because i'm creating several sql queries and an instance of HistoryDataController each time. So that's why i believe the problem lies somewhere in HistoryModel entities inside HistoryDataController objects or arrays, though, i can't find where exactly )

Comment: and yes, when historyList property of AppDelegate contains only text objects, not the HistoryModel entities it works stable.

Comment: So you comment that the init methods of HistoryModel aren't relevant because they aren't used, but then post code in HistoryDataController that DOES call one of them. Then you point out that if you don't use HistoryModel that it all works fine.  Do you still think it's not worth looking at the HistoryModel init methods? My gut guess is that `initWithWord:` isn't retaining or copying the autoreleased NSString it's being given.

Comment: ouch, i'm sorry, it's kind of mess in my head just now, you know how it is when learning a new language. added init methods. i believe you're right, but sorry me my incompetence, could you please point me what i should change? :)

Comment: i've added "self." before specifying "word" property and it worked. thank you! i guess that's an answer. but still, i don't know WHY does it happen, could you please give me a few variants of retaining a property in similar case with short explanation, if you have little time? it would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely have an issue in your -[HistoryModel initWithWord] You should retain (or better yet copy) the string that is being passed.

I would write it like this:

```
- (id)initWithWord:(NSString *)_word {
    [super init];
    self.word = _word; // this is same as [self setWord:_word]
    return self;
}
```

There are some who would say using the setter in your init is not a good practice. I'm not of that camp. But in any case, you need to be retaining or copying that string.

Then you have a similar issue in your app delegate where you are leaking each HistoryDataController as you create a new one. (and that happens every time that tableview appears). And you really should be retaining that array as well (although that hasn't caused a problem yet because you're leaking the HistoryDataControllers and therefore masking that issue so far.)

My general advice to you would be don't put off memory management. To come back later and try to get it right is complicated and error-prone even for an experienced developer. It is much, much easier to build the correct memory management techniques into the code as you write it. This means it's well worth your time to read the memory management guide first before you start coding something like this. You'll save yourself a lot of time and frustration.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now when it's working relatively stable i will read some info about memory management and try to fix these issues. But may i ask, what does it mean "you have a similar issue in your app delegate where you are leaking each HistoryDataController as you create a new one". I haven't fully got the concept of leaking ) What should i try to do to fix that issue?

Comment: If it's leaking, it's not working. It's just working temporarily.:) If you look in your -[SynonymAppDelegate initHistoryList], you create a new HistoryDataController each time. But then you don't release it. If all you require from that controller is the array, you should retain that array and then release the controller. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try to apply this :)